# Недопереведенные ресурсы в окне подписки на метку

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

Требуется перевод для всплывающей подсказки кнопки подписки на RSS-рассылку по метке и приглашения добавить описание метке в панельке подписки на метку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переводы добавлены, спасибо за наводку!

> [image]
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]